# Hibernate produces incorrect update statement

Tags: java, hibernate

I have this:

```
String hql = "UPDATE User u SET u.externalId = u.id WHERE u.directory.name = 'MySuperAwesomeName' AND u.externalId = null";
    Query query = session().createQuery(hql);
    query.executeUpdate();
```

And Hibernate throws Exception saying that:

```
Unexpected token JOIN, requires SET in statement [update user cross join  set external_id=id where name='MySuperAwesomeName' and (external_id is null)]
```

Please, help me pointing what I did wrong.

Mapping for User entity:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<!DOCTYPE hibernate-mapping PUBLIC "-//Hibernate/Hibernate Mapping DTD//EN" "http://www.hibernate.org/dtd/hibernate-mapping-3.0.dtd">
<hibernate-mapping>
    <class name="com.example.User" table="user" lazy="true">
        <id name="id" column="id" unsaved-value="null">
            <generator class="com.example.MySuperAwesomeGenerator"/>
        </id>
        <property name="name" column="user_name" type="string" not-null="true" length="255"/>
        <property name="externalId" column="external_id" type="string" not-null="false" length="255" index="idx_external_id"/>
        <many-to-one name="directory" column="directory_id" not-null="true" foreign-key="fk_user_dir_id" unique-key="uk_user_name_dir_id" class="com.example.DirectoryImpl"/>
    </class>
</hibernate-mapping>
```

Comment: please add you entity to help you better.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer might be changing this query into query with small subquery

```
UPDATE User u SET u.externalId = u.id WHERE u.directory.id IN (SELECT d.id FROM DirectoryImpl d where d.name = 'MySuperAwesomeName') AND u.externalId = NULL
```

It works.